# Sent data from client-side HTML to Wordpress server

Tags: wordpress, client-server

I'm running a Wordpress server, it has my web site, and I'm making a custom web page using HTML.

Now ... I want to make a `selectBox` and 'submit' button for the user...
How to get this data from the user/client side to my server so I can do stuff with it?

1- What should I type in HTML/web page?
2- How to do stuff with this data? (I have snippet plug-in installed).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table in DB and save customer's data each time they click on that submit button and get data from this table on your site.
Or you can use filter_hooks to save data.

Comment: I don't need to keep it, I need to act on it and send it as a REST API.
I just don't know how to "collect" it.
I mean, what do I do in the HTML file to send it to the wordpress server?
Should I make a rest API request to the the server? but then I should make an API on the wordpress server... any easier approach ?

Comment: Hmm, OK, I will check how to use  "filter_hooks" , and I guess I'll need snippets for that, right?  if you have any other idea like this I'd be happy to hear from you.. And thanks.